Why is a udev rule to symlink /dev/ttySPECIAL replacing /dev/tty with a symlink as well
On my target embedded system I have a udev rule that looks like:
KERNEL=="ttyACM?", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678", SYMLINK+="ttySPECIAL", MODE="0666"

When it's applied it creates a symlink from /dev/ttySPECIAl to /dev/ttyACM0 as expected. Unfortunately it also creates a symlink from /dev/tty to /dev/ttySPECIAL as well, which breaks the special /dev/tty device causing many command line tools like ls and ssh to break.
Is this expected behavior? Can I avoid it with a better-written rule somehow?  Or, is this a udev bug of some sort?
Edit: I found a removable USB serial adapter to build an example rule off-of.
KERNEL=="ttyUSB?", ATTRS{idVendor}=="06cd", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0121", SYMLINK+="ttyKEYSPAN"

If I put this into a rules file on a CentOS development box that is supposedly running the same systemd version 239 it behaves correctly. But if I add it into the custom rules on my target it also steals /dev/tty.  Presumably this implies an interaction with the built-in rules, but I can't debug this because the operation does not appear in the udev logs if I set them to debug level.  Only the original node for the correct device appears  when it parses the built-in rule, and the symlink of ttySPECIAL or ttyKEYSPAN appears when it later reads that rule file.
Are there any better ways to debug this?  Is it possible I have a broken patch?

I suspect you may have a mistyped extra copy of your udev rule still lurking somewhere. What does grep -r ttySPECIAL /etc/udev /usr/lib/udev tell you?

@telcoM It told me me I had editted the rules file with vim.  Remove the corresponding vim files and rebooting did not improve things.  No other rules files mention 'ttySPECIAL'. Deleting this line from the rules file causes my terminal to unbreak but breaks the service that talks to this device.

Something is clearly broken, but it is hard to say what exactly (udev? its rules? an early-initramfs devtmpfs set-up?). I wonder what udevadm info -q all -a -n /dev/ttyACM0 would output on your system? The output is likely to be rather long, and might be best stored in a public pastebin and linked to your question.

@telcoM Since that log is 130 lines and there's no attachment system I'll try to summarize: I see the various stages of connection from PCI bus, to USB controller, to USB port?, to USB device, to function on the USB device (DRIVERS=="cdc_acm"), to the tty assigned to it (KERNEL=="ttyACM0").   I see no evidence of any of the symlinks in this output.
